# GWT default server in development mode when Appengine is deactivated

Tags: gwt, application-server

I have been looking for the server that is user when we are in development mode, when we deactivate AppEngine! I am used to see the server in J2EE mode in eclipse but here I can't really tell which server is used! 
PS: I get this when I run the Web App:

```
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

does that mean that Apache is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, development mode runs an internal Jetty instance to serve your web application.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideDevMode